# Do I need to create separate forms for simple and Ajax thing in Django

Tags: django, jquery, django-templates

I have many forms which are working fine if i load them via normal http link.

The template is below

```
{% extends "app/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Create Account{% endblock %}
{% block media %}  {% include "app/media_template.html" %}  {% endblock %}
{% block heading %}Form{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

    <div id="stylized" class="myform">
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <h1>Account form</h1>
    <p>This is the basic look of my form without table</p>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}

            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}  {{ field }}

    {% endfor %}
   <button type="submit">Sign-up</button>
   <div class="spacer"></div>
    </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

But if i have to display via ajax then i just need the `div` box containing form only , i don't nedd all other html

So i want that if JS is not working then those forms still work via hyperlink.

I have 6 forms , do i have to create seoarate templae if i call via ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use part of your template in several places, you can put that part in a separate template, and include it wherever you need:

```
{% include "foo/bar.html" %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include

Comment: I think that can solve my problem to some extent. i will put all `form` in separate `ajax template` and then include that form in `General template`